# Javascript regex get string before second /

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = '#/promotionalMailer/test1';
```

output should be ==> `#/promotionalMailer`

I want the string before the second slash '/'

I have tried this so far:

```
 var str = '#/promotionalMailer/test1'; 
 var match = str.match(/([^\/]*\/){2}/)[0]; 
 alert(match);
```

But it comes with the second slash.

Comment: i have tried this so far..>>  var str = '#/promotionalMailer/test1';
var match = str.match(/([^\/]*\/){2}/)[0];
alert(match); But it comes with the second slash

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```js
var str = '#/promotionalMailer/test1/foo/bar/baz';

result = str.split('/').slice(0, 2).join('/')

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(result,0,3));
```

If you want regexes, then

```js
var str = '#/promotionalMailer/test1/foo/bar/baz';

result = str.match(/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*/)[0]

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(result,0,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

try `split`, `slice` and `join`

```
var str = '#/promotionalMailer/test1';

console.log( str.split("/").slice(0,2).join("/"));
```

Comment: But there can be n number of slashes '/'. I want the string before the second slash